# How to deploy contract in Truffle Console using Ganache

Tags: truffle

I'm developing contracts with Truffle Suite, using Ganache for tests. I would like to interact with contracts using truffle console. My project is starting from default configuration (truffle init).

I launched Ganache client, *truffle migrate*, then I'm doing the following:

```
truffle console
truffle(ganache)> let stor = await Storage.deployed();
Uncaught:
Error: Storage has not been deployed to detected network (network/artifact mismatch)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at Function.deployed (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/contract/lib/contract/constructorMethods.js:83:1)
    at Object.checkNetworkArtifactMatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/contract/lib/utils/index.js:245:1)
truffle(ganache)>
```

(Storage is my contract). What's wrong with deploy? *truffle migrate* gave me successful deploy:

```
truffle migrate

Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Everything is up to date, there is nothing to compile.



Starting migrations...
======================
> Network name:    'ganache'
> Network id:      5777
> Block gas limit: 6721975 (0x6691b7)


1_initial_migration.js
======================

   Deploying 'Migrations'
   ----------------------
   > transaction hash:    0x92c2fa06e4c3128e54a0aabcb713c6adcd2e544a28bb0c7af248f80341960b1f
   > Blocks: 0            Seconds: 0
   > contract address:    0x3E09162B6c7ECC804C5f82E7D91E8391F7f53e4F
   > block number:        1
   > block timestamp:     1623067868
   > account:             0xe1F0955a3A8Fd7ab6de489f5b32b1F70D7917Da9
   > balance:             99.99616114
   > gas used:            191943 (0x2edc7)
   > gas price:           20 gwei
   > value sent:          0 ETH
   > total cost:          0.00383886 ETH


   > Saving migration to chain.
   > Saving artifacts
   -------------------------------------
   > Total cost:          0.00383886 ETH


Summary
=======
> Total deployments:   1
> Final cost:          0.00383886 ETH
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to deploy your contract before trying to access it.truffle migrate log shows that you didn't deploy your contract.For that you have add `2_filename.js` before deploying